# coreData not displaying on collection view cell (swift4)

Tags: ios, core-data, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, swift4

This code right here display a array on a collection view. It works exactly how I want it to.

```
   import UIKit
import CoreData

class collectionVIEW: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{
    var sam = ["3","j"]
        var users = [User]()
    @IBOutlet var theIssues: UICollectionView!

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sam.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

         let cell =  collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! whyCollectionViewCell
    //            cell.general.text = users[indexPath.row].userName
          cell.general.text = sam[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

[image]

In my 2nd code. The code is slightly alerted to call core data and display on the cells. As you can see in the photo there are no cells visible. All I want to do is have the core data be displayed exactly how I was able to do in the first code set.

```
       import UIKit
import CoreData

class collectionVIEW: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{
    var sam = ["3","j"]
        var users = [User]()
    @IBOutlet var theIssues: UICollectionView!

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return users.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! whyCollectionViewCell
 cell.general.text = users[indexPath.row].userName
        //           cell.general.text = sam[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

[image]

CORE DATA

```
import UIKit

import CoreData

class cdHandler: NSObject {

    private class func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        let appdeleagetzz = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        return appdeleagetzz.persistentContainer.viewContext

    }

    class func saveObject(userName: String) -> Bool {
        let context = getContext()
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "User", in: context)

        let managedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

        managedObject.setValue(userName, forKey: "userName")


        do {
            try context.save()
            return true

        } catch {
            return false

        }
    }


    class func fetchObject() -> [User]? {
        let context = getContext()
        var users: [User]? = nil

        do {
            users = try context.fetch(User.fetchRequest())



            return users


        } catch {
            return users

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the code that loads your users array from core data?

Comment: the array has nothing to do with core data its just in that view controller. @Paulw11

Comment: The code shows that the `users` array is used by your collectionView. How do you get the data into that array?

Comment: var users = [User]() is the coreData. Do you want me to upload the core data vc to this question

Comment: That declares an empty array of `User` objects (and presumably `User` is your `NSManagedObject` subclass) but you need to actually fetch the data from your persistent store into the array.

Comment: I added my vc of coreData at the end of my question

Comment: So where you do *call `fetchObject`*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all do not return an optional in `fetchObject()`, return an empty array on failure:

```
class func fetchObject() -> [User] {
     do {
        let context = getContext()
        return try context.fetch(User.fetchRequest())
     } catch {
         return [User]()
     }
}
```

Second of all, to answer the question, you have to call `fetchObject()` in `viewDidLoad` to load the data

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    users = cdHandler.fetchObject()
    theIssues.reloadData()
}
```

Note: Please conform to the naming convention that class names start with a capital letter.